# Using str_replace() in Echo

Tags: php

In PHP programming can we use `str_replace();` in `echo '';` 
 If it is possible then please show me an example.

Comment: `echo str_replace(' World','','Hello World');` ??

Comment: -1 at least try it first, or tell us what you have tried and why you can't get it to work.

Comment: omg! okay, assuming a `echo` has a out like this> `echo 'I think people here are so $say';` then how, in this case, `str_replace();` can be use

Comment: `echo 'I think people here are so '.str_replace('cool', 'mean', $say);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo str_replace('dog', 'cat', 'thats an ugly dog');
```

output is "thats an ugly cat" from "thats an ugly dog";

Example: http://codepad.org/b63nu4Ie